# Finding the alphabetically last word in a file read using scanner

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment where I have to find the alphabetically last word in a file read using scanner. Most of the examples I looked up suggested using arrays or arrayLists but I CANNOT use arrays or arrayLists for this part so collections is out of the question. So I have been trying to use compareTo() to compare strings in a lexicographical order. So far I have something like:

```
while (read.hasNext()) {
    String s = read.next().toLowerCase();
    }
```

Now my question is how would I implement compare to in this instance? I tried doing something like

```
 if (string1.compareTo(string2) < 0) {
     lastWord = string1
}
```

But I am having trouble creating two different strings to compare with. Any ideas or hints would be very helpful.

Comment: what is you problem? one string is from file, another string is lastWord. initially lastword is empty string

Comment: Well so I have a bunch of words read from a file and I need to get the alphabetically last word in the file.

Comment: hint: imagine that you have only 1 word in file, what will you do? then imagine that second word added to the same file

Comment: Well lets say I have string s outside of the while loop, it gives me a single word. Now when its in a loop I could compare it to another string. so do I define an empty string outside the loop and them compare string s to that empty string? For example 
'if(s1.compareTo(tempString) < 0) { 
   lastWord = tempstring; }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
String lastWord = "";
while (read.hasNext()) {
    String s = read.next().toLowerCase();
    if (lastWord.compareTo(s) < 0)
        lastWord = s;
}
```

Or taking @Ulvon's suggestion into consideration you can preserve the string unchanged.

```
String lastWord = "";
while (read.hasNext()) {
    String s = read.next();
    if (lastWord.compareToIgnoreCase(s) < 0)
        lastWord = s;
}
```

N.B. I haven't compiled either solution so the syntax may not be quite right.

Comment: This definitely works. I had something similar before but instead of comparing lastWord to s I compared s to lastWord. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String#compareToIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29). You have to be careful as according to documentation:

> Note that this method does not take locale into account, and will result in an unsatisfactory ordering for certain locales

If Locale comparison matters, [use Collator#compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#compare%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). Iterate as your while() loop is doing, run the comparison and if it's bigger than zero, that would be your current alphabetically last word. Store it until another last word is reached.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

I want to comment, but seems like I don't have enough reputation.

All you need is save a neutral `lastWord`. Before iterate the file content.

```
String lastWord = "";
while (read.hasNext()) {
    String s = read.next();
    if (lastWord.compareToIgnoreCase(s) < 0 || lastWord.equals(""))
        lastWord = s;
}
```